# MATCH (somefeald) AGAINST ('+".$_GET['search']."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Why does this SQL query return a blank result?

```
select
 webs.title,webs.disc,webs.logo,webs.id
from 
 webs
 JOIN rel ON rel.webid=webs.id
 JOIN catagory on catagory.id=rel.catid 
where 
  webs.app!=0 
  AND MATCH (webs.title,webs.city,webs.state,webs.url,catagory.catname) AGAINST ('+".$_GET['search']."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This is a query for multiples searches in multiple tables and fields.
I also want to order the result by the best matching word.

Comment: Note: This query is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Be sure to properly escape `$_GET['search']`.

Comment: what do you have that + for after AGAINST ?

Comment: no problem with $_GET['search'] value i tested it

Comment: If you remove the `AND MATCH ... IN BOOLEAN MODE)` do you get results? if not then remove the joins and check again, try to pin point the problem (the joins or the filters).

Comment: i test this 
SELECT * FROM webs WHERE MATCH (title,city,state,url) AGAINST ('+".$_GET['search']."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"; and i got result but again i repeat joins is must required

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use "MATCH() ... AGAINST", first create fulltext index on the field which you want in match.